# JQuery functions .addClass(), .attr() and .find() not working in IE7, need workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a table and trying to add some CSS as well as some attributes.  I can't seem to find any workarounds for IE7.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$.each(eat,function() {

//Builds tablerows
var row = document.createElement("tr");
var cellReportId = document.createElement("td");
cellReportId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.reportId));
var cellDescription = document.createElement("td");
cellDescription.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.description));
var cellDrawingNumber = document.createElement("td");
cellDrawingNumber.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.drawingNumber));

row.appendChild(cellReportId);
row.appendChild(cellDescription);
row.appendChild(cellDrawingNumber);


$(self.tblResults[0]).append(row);
})


$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr').addClass("DynamicTableTR"); 
$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr:not(:first)').attr("onmouseover", "this.style.background='#EDEED5'");
$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr:not(:first)').attr("onmouseout", "this.style.background='white'");
$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr:first').addClass("DynamicTableHeaderRow");
$(self.tblResults[0]).addClass("DynamicTable");

}
```

The part at the bottom doesn't work in IE:

```
$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr').addClass("DynamicTableTR"); 
$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr:not(:first)').attr("onmouseover", "this.style.background='#EDEED5'");
$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr:not(:first)').attr("onmouseout", "this.style.background='white'");
$(self.tblResults[0]).find('tr:first').addClass("DynamicTableHeaderRow");
```

If tried several different approaches in the $.each loop to format the 'row' element without any luck.  The .attr() function will not work in IE either it seems.

On the addClass() function it does work here:

```
$(self.tblResults[0]).addClass("DynamicTable");
```

However it does not work if I try to apply it to the row in $.each loop like this:

```
$(row).addClass("DynamicTableTR");
```

I can't seem to find any workaround for IE.

EDIT:

The issue is the css/attributes are not getting applied to the s that I'm creating.

And the defintion of self is:

```
var self = this;    //Capture the current self, outside of the $.each loop
```

tblResults is just a  already defined on my page.

Comment: each call to document.createelement is very slow in javascript -- you would be better served to make a text string of the row html and then add that.

Comment: "it does not work" means: it does not find the TR or it does not add the class? (selector, or addClass() issue ?

Comment: where is the def for self -- that might make the problem clearer.

Comment: I edited the post to answer those two questions.

Comment: Also Hogan I was just adding the <tr> as a string but I thought by doing it as createElement then it would allow me to tie some attributes to them, which I need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this alternative, comment if you have any issues...without your setup I can't test completely:

Updated to fix the XSS possibility as [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) pointed out:

```
var tbl = $(self.tblResults[0]);
$.each(eat,function() {
  $("<tr class='DynamicTableTR' />")
    .append($("<td></td>").text(this.reportId))
    .append($("<td></td>").text(this.description))
    .append($("<td></td>").text(this.drawingNumber))
   .appendTo(tbl);
});

// This next .hover() could be replaced with a CSS rule:
// .DynamicTableTR:hover { background: #EDEED5; }
// Won't work in IE 6 though, maybe some other older browsers

tbl.find('tr:not(:first)').hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background","#EDEED5");
 }, function() { 
  $(this).css("background", "white");
 });
tbl.addClass("DynamicTable").find('tr:first').addClass("DynamicTableHeaderRow");
```

If you're using jQuery 1.4+, it recognizes snippets like this and offers a great deal of optimization behind the scenes when doing looping inserts.

Comment: You've just introduced a potential cross-site-scripting security hole in with the HTML string-slinging. If the `description` has `<` or `&` characters in it, you've got problems. The `createTextNode` methods, and jQuery `text()` avoid this problem.

Comment: @bobince - Good point :)  I updated the answer in case anyone else comes across this later.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(...).attr("onmouseover", "this.style.background='#EDEED5'");
```

You can't set event handlers by string using `onX` attributes in IE, and you shouldn't generally set inline event handlers from string anyway. Better to use a real JS function object:

```
$(...).mouseover(function() { this.style.background='#EDEED5' });
```

or, if you want to re-use the same function object (and not form a closure) for efficiency reasons:

```
function row_onmouseover() {
    this.style.background= '#EDEED5';
}
...

$(...).mouseover(row_onmouseover);
```

There again, unless you absolutely definitely need your hover effect to work on IE6, I think you're better off doing it with a (much simpler) CSS `:hover` rule. IE6 users don't need pretty things. :-)